# Getting the table name from a Spark Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

If I have a dataframe created as follows:

```
df = spark.table("tblName")
```

Is there anyway that I can get back tblName from df?

Comment: Surprised this has no solution! I have the exact same question: I have the Spark Dataframe, and now I want the table name

Comment: Doesnt look like it sadly. You should think its rather straight forward. But since the dataframe could be from a lot of different things I think they didnt offer something to get the table name back.

Comment: 2 months left until 2023 and there is still no solution for this simple problem...

Comment: It is important to understand, that the table and it's name is not representing DataFrame. After creation of a table it has its own lifecycle. What you're describing looks as serious hack in the code which is highly recommended not to do. 
Instead you may pas a tuple down the execution flow. This tuple should contain your df and the name which was associated at some step with it. This explicit approach will make the code even more readable.

Answer (score 1):

We can extract tablename from a dataframe by parsing `unresolved logical plan`.
Please follow the method below:

```
def getTableName(df: DataFrame): String = {

  Seq(df.queryExecution.logical, df.queryExecution.optimizedPlan).flatMap{_.collect{
      case LogicalRelation(_, _, catalogTable: Option[CatalogTable], _) =>
        if (catalogTable.isDefined) {
          Some(catalogTable.get.identifier.toString())
        } else None
      case hive: HiveTableRelation => Some(hive.tableMeta.identifier.toString())
    }
  }.flatten.head
}
```

---

```
scala> val df = spark.table("db.table")

scala> getTableName(df)
res: String = `db`.`table`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract it from the plan:

```
df.logicalPlan().argString().replace("`","")
```

Comment: Hi, tried on pyspark 2.3.1 and I got this error: `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'logicalPlan'`. What is the version you tried this?

Answer (score 0):

Following utility function may be helpful to determine the table name from given DataFrame.

```
def get_dataframe_tablename(df: pyspark.sql.DataFrame) -> typing.Optional[str]:
    """
    If the dataframe was created from an underlying table (e.g. spark.table('dual') or
    spark.sql("select * from dual"), this function will return the
    fully qualified table name (e.g. `default`.`dual`) as output otherwise it will return None.

    Test on: python 3.7, spark 3.0.1, but it should work with Spark >=2.x and python >=3.4 too
    Examples:
        >>> get_dataframe_tablename(spark.table('dual'))
        `default`.`dual`
        >>> get_dataframe_tablename(spark.sql("select * from dual"))
        `default`.`dual`

    It inspects the output of `df.explain()` to determine that the df was created from a table or not
    :param df: input dataframe whose underlying table name will be return
    :return:  table name or None
    """

    def _explain(_df: pyspark.sql.DataFrame) -> str:
        # df.explain() does not take parameter to accept the out and dump the output on stdout
        # by default
        import contextlib
        import io
        with contextlib.redirect_stdout(io.StringIO()) as f:
            _df.explain()
        f.seek(0)  # Rewind stream position
        explanation = f.readlines()[1]  # Ignore first output line(#Physical Plan...)
        return explanation

    pattern = re.compile("Scan hive (.+), HiveTableRelation (.+?), (.+)")
    output = _explain(df)
    match = pattern.search(output)
    return match.group(2) if match else None
```

Answer (score 0):

Below three line of code will give table and database name

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FileSourceScanExec
df=session.table("dealer")
df.queryExecution.sparkPlan.asInstanceOf[FileSourceScanExec].tableIdentifier
```

Comment: Hi @codingclues, where does the table `dealer` come from? I'm wondering if any configurations/settings that need to apply on Spark session to use this call `spark.table()`.

Answer (score 0):

Any answer on this one yet? I found a way but it's probably not the prettiest. You can access the tablename by retrieving the physical execution plan and then doing some string splitting magic on it.

Let's say you have a table from `database_name.tblName`. The following should work:

```
execution_plan = df.__jdf.queryExecution().simpleString()
table_name = string.split('FileScan')[1].split('[')[0].split('.')[1]
```

The first line will return your execution plan in a string format. That will look similar to this:

```
== Physical Plan ==\n*(1) ColumnarToRow\n+- FileScan parquet database_name.tblName[column1#2880,column2ban#2881] Batched: true, DataFilters: [], Format: Parquet, Location: PreparedDeltaFileIndex[dbfs:/mnt/lake/database_name/table_name], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<column1:string,column2:string...\n\n'
```

After that you can run some string splitting to access the relevant information. The first string split gets you all the elements of `FileScan`- you are interested in the second element, then before and after the `[`- here the first element is of interest. The second string  split after `.` will return `tblName`

Answer (score -2):

You can create table from df. But if table is a local temporary view or a global temporary view you should drop it (sqlContext.dropTempTable) before create a table with same name or use create or replace function (spark.createOrReplaceGlobalTempView or spark.createOrReplaceTempView). If table is temp table you can create table with same name without error

```
#Create data frame
>>> d = [('Alice', 1)]
>>> test_df = spark.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(d), ['name','age'])
>>> test_df.show()
+-----+---+
| name|age|
+-----+---+
|Alice|  1|
+-----+---+

#create tables
>>> test_df.createTempView("tbl1")
>>> test_df.registerTempTable("tbl2")
>>> sqlContext.tables().show()
+--------+---------+-----------+
|database|tableName|isTemporary|
+--------+---------+-----------+
|        |     tbl1|       true|
|        |     tbl2|       true|
+--------+---------+-----------+

#create data frame from tbl1
>>> df = spark.table("tbl1")
>>> df.show()
+-----+---+
| name|age|
+-----+---+
|Alice|  1|
+-----+---+

#create tbl1 again with using df data frame. It will get error
>>> df.createTempView("tbl1")
    raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: "Temporary view 'tbl1' already exists;"

#drop and create again
>>> sqlContext.dropTempTable('tbl1')
>>> df.createTempView("tbl1")
>>> spark.sql('select * from tbl1').show()
+-----+---+
| name|age|
+-----+---+
|Alice|  1|
+-----+---+


#create data frame from tbl2 and replace name value
>>> df = spark.table("tbl2")
>>> df = df.replace('Alice', 'Bob')
>>> df.show()
+----+---+
|name|age|
+----+---+
| Bob|  1|
+----+---+

#create tbl2 again with using df data frame
>>> df.registerTempTable("tbl2")
>>> spark.sql('select * from tbl2').show()
+----+---+
|name|age|
+----+---+
| Bob|  1|
+----+---+
```